# how to add tabletools to existing datatables?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables, tabletools

OK guys, I have a page with a dinamic table using jquery datatables

```
 <div class="widget">

<div class="widget-head">
<h5>Usuarios</h5>
</div>

<div class="widget-body">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="data-table" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><?php echo lang('index_fname_th');?></th>
        <th><?php echo lang('index_lname_th');?></th>
        <th><?php echo lang('index_email_th');?></th>
        <th><?php echo lang('index_groups_th');?></th>
                <th><?php echo lang('index_code_th');?></th>
        <th><?php echo lang('index_status_th');?></th>
        <th><?php echo lang('index_action_th');?></th>
                <th><?php echo lang('index_net_th');?></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
                                    <?php foreach ($users as $user):?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($user->first_name,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($user->last_name,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($user->email,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');?></td>
            <td>
        <?php foreach ($user->groups as $group):?>
            <?php echo anchor("auth/edit_group/".$group->id, htmlspecialchars($group->name,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8')) ;?><br />
                <?php endforeach?>
            </td>
                        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($user->codigo,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');?></td>
            <td><?php echo ($user->active) ? anchor("auth/deactivate/".$user->id, lang('index_active_link')) : anchor("auth/activate/". $user->id, lang('index_inactive_link'));?></td>
            <td><?php echo anchor("auth/edit_user/".$user->id, 'Edit') ;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($user->red,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
                                </tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<th><?php echo lang('index_fname_th');?></th>
        <th><?php echo lang('index_lname_th');?></th>
        <th><?php echo lang('index_email_th');?></th>
        <th><?php echo lang('index_groups_th');?></th>
                <th><?php echo lang('index_code_th');?></th>
        <th><?php echo lang('index_status_th');?></th>
        <th><?php echo lang('index_action_th');?></th>
                <th><?php echo lang('index_net_th');?></th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="widget-foot">

</div>

</div>
```

edit:

this is my js script:

```
/* Data Table */
/* ********** */

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#data-table').dataTable({
       "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
         "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip'
    });
});

/* ****************************** */
```

and my css is the big file you download from datatables web page.

I have spent almost a week trying to add tabletools to my code i just cant understand the documentation, can anyone point me in the right direction please.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Do you mean the "table tools" of "Data Tables"?

Comment: so what is it doing or NOT doing .... or is it working or not working ... or does the table show up or not show up ... Also where is you header to see the JS and CSS required for the data tables to work ...

Comment: well data tables is working fine, i just waant to add the table tools

Answer (score 1):

**first import the data tabletools package
after that unzipped the folder where the your project folder
after that include the source file
like this**

```
<script src="http://localhost:88/project_name/DataTables-1.10.7/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:88/project_name/DataTables-1.10.7/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:88/project_name/DataTables-1.10.7/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://localhost:88/project_name/DataTables-1.10.7/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css"rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://localhost:88/project_name/DataTables-1.10.7/extensions/TableTools/css/dataTables.tableTools.css"rel="stylesheet">
```

and after that 
include the jquery function

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#index1').DataTable( {
dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
tableTools: {
        "sSwfPath": "http://localhost:88/project_name/DataTables1.10.7/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf"
    }
} );

} );
</script>
```

here index1 is table id

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

Table tools are a PLUGIN to datatables, a number of steps are required to get this to work.

I cannot see your header, so I do not know what you have included (js,css)

First you need to have all the scripts/css for the standard data tables.

In addition to that you need to go https://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/plug-ins and download/save the javascript and add that to your header to be loaded, you also need to download, save and load the table tools css sheet in your header as well - again I cannot see that you have done so.

Go to https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/examples/simple.html, save all the HTML/JS/CSS locally and create a file to test that locally. Once that is working with external files start including the files (js/css) on your server - if its still working you know you have all the required libraries.

Then try your code - if it does not work put a SIMPLE table in their - you could even use the one from the table tools site.

If its still not working what does the debugging console tell you (Firefox/Chrome)?

Answer (score 0):

Add tabletools swf file to your datatable options, and add the datatables js and css files to your code

```
$('#status_table').DataTable({
    "tableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "packages/datatables-tabletools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
    }
});
```